# Java's popularity in Internet Algorithmics (Search, Big Data etc.)

Tags: java, c++, performance, algorithm, programming-languages

I have been writing C/C++ code for years. Recently started doing lot of Java too because some of the very fine products that I am using to solve my computing problems are all written in Java (Example: Lucene/Solr, Hadoop, Neo4j, OpenNLP etc.).

I am seeing this chage since last 3-4 years that Java has really got very popular atleast in Internet Algorithms (Clustering, Search, Big Data & so on). Though their are counterparts of the products that I have mentioned above in C++ (like for Search Sphinx written in C++ is a great option, Google has its Map Reduce written in C++ etc.)

I am just curious to know what are the factors & strength's that are making Java very popular these days **specially in the Information Retrieval & Big data domain**.

I just wanted to know the strengths of Java which is making it very popular in Internet Algorithms space? Is it just because of platform independence thing?

Comment: Ah the old java vs. c++ performance story. 98% of the benchmarks out there are done by people who have no clue how to benchmark either language and the other 2% that do, test specific things because they understand that blanket statements are useless. In the end c++ just makes writing these kind of really large program harder than it has to be - especially considering that the stuff where c++ has advantages (lower memory pressure, sse, inexact fp math,..) aren't especially useful for these things.

Comment: For the very domain you've specified, a pure CPU-bound performance is of a least importance.

Comment: @Yavar, it is a memory-bound operation, not CPU-bound. No number crunching L1-is-big-enough algorithms involved at all, which renders the difference between managed and unmanaged irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that Java and C++ perform at a similar level outside of the arbitrary, contrived situations which are so often used to prove that X is faster than Y.

Once you factor in network round-trip times and other, real world delays, I can't see a C++ application offering a measurable advantage over a Java application simply due to being C++ as opposed to Java.  You will, however, see a measurable difference between a well-written application and a poorly-written application.

Answer (score 1):

plattform independance is a nice feature, but doesn't always work in java. depending on what you do

java gets its popularity for the fact, that it's more safe than c++

you can not use pointer arithmetics and you can not manage memory allocation on your own

if something wents terribly wrong, you get an exception or an error, or the program just crashes but in java you are relatively sure not to continue doing things you definitely don't want to do

yes you can do all that in c++, but that's not the question, isn't it?